# Enforcing parameter position in java methods using style checker

Tags: java, parameter-passing, checkstyle

We have a use case where data is partitioned by a partitionId and this partitionId is used in multiple places. From the code readability, it will be much more easier if this partitionId is the first or last parameter in all the methods. Is there any way to enforce this using check style or find bugs in java?